# Are finitely generated objects in a locally Noetherian category also finitely presented?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, noetherian

Let $\mathcal C$ be a locally Noetherian category. Then, we know that every finitely generated object is Noetherian.

I cannot seem to be able to prove that Noetherian objects are finitely presented. A locally Noetherian category is locally coherent and so we know that finitely presented objects in it are coherent.

But are Noetherian objects automatically coherent?

I would be grateful for a proof or a precise reference.

Comment: According to N. Popescu, _Abelian categories with applications to rings and modules,_ LMS Monographs, 1973, 5.8 Exercise 2, noetherian objects are finitely presented (in general). I have not checked this, but you might find a proof when following the references given at the end of this section.

Comment: @FredRohrer There are groups that are noetherian (no ascending chain of subgroups) and not finitely presented. So there are probably extra hypotheses (abelian category?).

Comment: Dear Yves, yes, this is about abelian categories.

Comment: Dear Noetherian, it seems that some of the notions you refer to may be defined in different ways. May I ask you to specify which definitions you use, and in particular what kind of categories (abelian, Grothendieck, ...) you are interested in?

Comment: "noetherian objects are finitely presented (in general)": this is not true. For example, let k be a field and A be the commutative k-algebra of polynomials in infinitely many variables on k. Let S be k seen as a A-module (with zero action of all of the variables). Then S is a simple object in the category of A-modules, in particular it is noetherian. But S is not finitely presented because the kernel of the canonical epimorphism A->>k is the augmentation ideal, which is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 1):

If your locally noetherian abelian category is also a Grothendieck category, it is true that every finitely generated object of it is finitely presented. Indeed, in a locally finitely generated Grothendieck category, a finitely generated object X is finitely presented if and only if for any short exact sequence 0 -> T-> Y -> X -> 0 with Y finitely generated, T is finitely generated. As finitely generated=noetherian is stable under subobjects in a locally noetherian category, this condition is free. Alternatively, you can use the classical equivalence between a locally noetherian Grothendieck category and the category of left-exact functors from a small artinian abelian category to abelian groups. If the locally noetherian category does not satisfy (AB5), what is your definition of "finitely generated"?